# Finding first return time in an infinite markov chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

[image]

I have an infinite markov chain that looks like this. I need to show that the chain is recurrent by computing the first return time to 0 for the chain that started at 0. Intuitively to me, this makes sense because any state will eventually return to state 0. However, I am not quite sure how to formulate this for formally, using definitions of recurrence and first return time.

I need to calculate,
$
E(T_0 |X_0 = 0) 
$
where $T_0$ is the first passage time to state 0.

I  set up a set of equations using first-step analysis...

\begin{align}
T_{00} =E(T_0 |X_0 = 0) =1+1(T_{10}) \\ T_{10} = E(T_0 |X_0 = 1) = 1+ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(T_{20})
\end{align}

However, I realized that I'll have infinite number of equations like this and I am not quite sure how to approach this.

Do I just have a completely wrong understanding of what "first return time" is? Thanks for any help!

Comment: $T_{00} = 1+1 \times T_{00} \implies 0 = 1$?

Comment: Oops, typo! Edited it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To figure out how recurrent this Markov chain isn't, you'll probably want to know two things:

1. The probability that, starting at $0$, you'll ever return to $0$.
2. The expected number of steps it takes to return to $0$.

In this Markov chain, it's very clear what the path has to be if we never return to $0$, and therefore (1) is easy to solve. Let $T_0$ be the number of steps to return to $0$, with $T_0=\infty$ if we never do. Then
\begin{align}
   \Pr[T_0 \ge 1] &= 1  & \text{($T_0$ can never be 0)} \\
   \Pr[T_0 \ge 2] &= 1  & \text{(going $0 \to 1$)} \\
   \Pr[T_0 \ge 3] &= 1 \cdot \tfrac12 & \text{(going $0 \to 1 \to 2$)} \\
   \Pr[T_0 \ge 4] &= 1 \cdot \tfrac12 \cdot \tfrac23 = \tfrac13 & \text{(going $0 \to 1 \to 2 \to 3$)} \\
   \Pr[T_0 \ge k+1] &= 1 \cdot \tfrac12 \cdots \tfrac{k-1}{k} = \tfrac1{k} & \text{(going $0 \to 1 \to \dots \to k$)}
\end{align}
and because $\lim_{k \to \infty} \Pr[T_0 \ge k] = \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac1{k-1} = 0$, we know that $\Pr[T_0{=}\infty] = 0$: with probability $1$, we do return to $0$ eventually.

To figure out (2), the expected number of steps it takes to return to $0$, it's easiest to use the formula
$$
   \mathbb E[X] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k \cdot \Pr[X=k] = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^k \Pr[X=k] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{k=j}^\infty \Pr[X=k] = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \Pr[X \ge j].
$$
In this case, 
$$
   \sum_{j=1}^\infty \Pr[T_0\ge j] = 1 + 1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \frac15 + \dotsb
$$
which is the harmonic series, which diverges. So $\mathbb E[T_0] = \infty$, which means that the Markov chain is null-recurrent: it returns to $0$ with probability $1$, but the expected number of steps until it does so is infinite.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - using probability makes much more sense to me. What do they mean when they say "compute the first return time to 0 for the chain starting at 0?" Are they asking me to compute the expected time to return to 0? Does the term "first return time" have an official mathematical definition?

Comment: That is what they're asking (except whether or not they mean an expected value or a random variable is left up to context; here, since we're "computing" it, it's the expected value). The language "first return time" just means what it says: there could be several points in time when we return to $0$, and the first return time refers to the earliest.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong here - but isn't the first return time here then infinite? From what I understand, (expectedly) it should take infinite number of steps for this markov chain to go back to where it started. Am I reasoning this properly, or am I completely missing something here? Thanks a ton

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what's happening here. (To be absolutely clear: an infinite number of steps *in expectation*.)

Comment: You said that $E[T_0] = 1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} +...$. Why is there an additional 1? Is that a typo, am I not summing up the probabilities properly? The expectation should still diverge regardless but trying to fully understand the math here.

Comment: There's an additional $1$ because $\Pr[T_0 \ge 1]$ is $1$ and $\Pr[T_0 \ge 2]$ is also $1$: we always take at least $2$ steps to return to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to argue directly along the definitions.
For this, let the hitting time be $T=\inf\{n \geq 1: X_n=0\}$ and $f_{00}^{(n)}=P(T=n |X_0=0)$.

Observe the following:

$f_{00}^{(1)}=0$

$f_{00}^{(2)}=1*1/2=1/2$

$f_{00}^{(3)}=1*1/2*1/3=1/6$

$f_{00}^{(4)}=1*1/2*2/3*1/4=1/12$ and so on...

Hence, $f_{00}^{(n)}=\frac{1}{(n-1)n}$.

In order to check for recurrence, we argue along the definition:
$f_{00}^{(*)}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{00}^{(n)}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-1)n}=1$.

So state 0 is recurrent.

Since the chain is irreducible and state 0 is recurrent, the chain is recurrent.

The chain is null recurrent as
$E(T|X_0=0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n*f_{00}^{(n)}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n*\frac{1}{(n-1)n}=\infty$

Alternative Argumentation: As the chain is irreducible, one could also show that there exists no invariant distribution and conclude that the chain is not positive recurrent. Since the chain is recurrent by above considerations, the chain must be null recurrent.